# UILabel font issue in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

i have a label  and i want make its font bold pragmatically .I try following code.its not working .please give me suggetion.Thanks.

```
[label1 setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Bold" size:14.0 ]];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want Helvetica, the default font, you can use `[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]`. If you want to explicitly name a font, you may need to use a dash (`Helvetica-Bold`). [This website](http://iosfonts.com/) has a list of font names for all the built-in fonts in iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Try out code:

```
[label1 setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:14.0 ]];
```

Hope this helps you.